# How to convert a spaceless data into tab delimited in R?

Tags: r, dataset, matrix

I have a data set in form of:(this is just an example)

```
1324501020
3241030205
4332020134
```

which each row represents responses of an examinee to a set of items on a test.
The data are stored in a text file (e.g. data.txt) but I need to convert them into a matrix format such that each number be place in a cell, like this:

```
1 3 2 4 5 0 1 0 2 0
3 2 4 1 0 3 0 2 0 5
4 3 3 2 0 2 0 1 3 4
```

in other words, the final data set supposed to be a matrix of numbers in which columns contain responses to each item and rows are examinees.
Any idea??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x <- read.fwf(file = "c:\\whatever\\data.txt", width=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
```

Oh, and have a wonderful trip to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply!this is my first experience with StackOverflow! I like your solution by the point is that sometimes I don't know the number of items.Is there any way of doing that without using 'width' ?

Comment: @Amin As far as I know "width" is a needed argument. It's hard to feed a fixed width data without telling the software when to stop. I have tried to replace it with rep(1,10) but it didn't seem to work. Perhaps you can consult the help file of "read.fwf" for more details.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight : I would be shocked if `rep(1,10)` were not exactly equivalent to `c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)`.  @Amin: if you don't know the number of items you can try reading just the first line as text and examining it: `fn <- "data.txt"; r <- readLines(fn,n=1); n_items <- nchar(r); read.fwf(fn, width=rep(1,n_items))`

Answer (score 1):

If the data is in a text file and the file contains only data like shown, then the best approach is probably the `read.fwf` approach as described by @Penguin_Knight.  But if there are additional data fields in the file that don't fit the fixed width format, or if the data has been copied or grabbed in a different way so that it is already in a character vector in R, then here are some other options.

You can still use the `read.fwf` approach with a `textConnection`.

You can use the `strsplit` function to split the strings into the individual digits and use `as.numeric` to convert them to numbers.

You can use the `strapply` function from the gsubfn package to match individual digits and extract them (and pass to `as.numeric` again).